# How to fix restoring nuget packages error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

After a couple of weeks I revisited my .NET C# project in Visual Studio 2010. I changed just one line in source code and tried to rebuild the project and I get this error:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages:  could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))

I don't have the slightest clue why this error appeared. Nothing was changed, somehow this nuget got corrupted.
I have done a lot of searching via google but found nothing that would get me on the right track.

is it possible to remove nuget all together, because it is nothing but a cause of grief?

Answer (score 6):

I've faced with the same issue:
I solved this problem by going to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and clicking on OK

source:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1015106/exception-occurred-exception-from-hresult-0x800200.html

I also had this call stack:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))
    at EnvDTE.Property.get_Value()
    at NuGetVSExtension.OutputConsoleLogger.<GetMSBuildVerbosityLevelAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at NuGetVSExtension.OutputConsoleLogger.<<Start>b__24_0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
    at NuGetVSExtension.OutputConsoleLogger.Start()
    at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.NuGetUI.BeginOperation()
    at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<PerformActionImplAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you right click your solution in Visual Studio. Do you see any option called "Enable NuGet Package Restore"?

If yes, try to click on it and rebuild again.

Comment: Well, yes. But I am afraid of using it. Everything with connection to nuget makes me very vary, because mostly it ends up in broken projects or unnneded imports and a lot of trouble. I wish there was a way to eliminate nuget.

Comment: i tried it. And just as I was afraid. Now it doesn't show any errors. It just does not build. Nothing helps, clean, build, rebuild... nothing.,

Comment: Try clear your nuget package cache. In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General and choose the browse button. Delete the cache.

Comment: Also delete the content of your [SOLUTION PATH]\packages folder. That will make sure to download the correct packages from NuGet based on you packages.config.